# Does jQuery have an AJAJ method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Does jQuery have a method for asynchronous javascript and JSON (AJAJ), like `jQuery.ajax()` for asynchronous javascript and XML ?

Also just noticed there isn't an `ajaj` tag.

Comment: The "x" is the least important letter in "ajax" :) The browser doesn't insist that responses be XML; they can be anything.

Comment: And the direct answer is **no** because it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Pointy the answer has to be async, no direct answers accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acronym 'AJAX' was created back in the day, when XML was the format most often used for the data returned. Today, the data format returned is typically JSON, but we still use the acronym AJAX -- for any asynchronous HTTP request and response. The data format returned can be anything that makes sense for your implementation; the technology behind it will be the same. So you would use `jQuery.ajax` for your JSON. jQuery also has a shorthand method you could look at, [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery AJAX Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

or more up to date: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

success is replaced by done... check other changes...