# Javascript Dynamic filters

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax

I'm looking for examples to make a filter (in the left sidebar) that when clicking on a filter updates the page content (Query), and if (the filter) has subcategories, it displays them down the selected filter (in the left sidebar).

I found that AJAX is used for this, but this works with XML files, and I use JSON.
Can AJAX be used with JSON?

Thank you very much to anyone who can contribute something.
Greetings.

Comment: JSON is just a data format. AJAX was poorly named. It's really just a means of transferring data between the browser and a server. So yes, AJAX works with JSON and I would say is encouraged.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703689/does-jquery-have-an-ajaj-method) has information that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mike!, I think AJAX is the best solution for this.

Comment: I was designing the sequence of macro steps that the user triggers when he clicks on a filter. I hope to help as an example to understand the process and the role of each technology in this.

Comment: 1.-Get the data of selected filter (Javascript / Client)
2.-Generation of JSON file with the data obtained in [1] (Javascript / AJAX / Client)
3.-Sending JSON file to the Server (Javascript / AJAX / Client)
4.-Process of JSON file and generation of the Query (NodeJS / Server)
5.-Query Execution in Database (MySQL / Server)
6.-Recordset process obtained in [5] and generation of JSON file (MySQL / NodeJS / Server)
7.-Sending JSON file obtained in [6] to the Client (NodeJS / AJAX / Server)
8.-Process of JSON file and data load in HTML (AJAX / Javascript / Client)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is definitely a valid data type for AJAX.  All you have to do is specify the data-type in your call, otherwise it will default to text. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url : 'http://example.com',
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```